# min-height fixes the height

Tags: html, css, height

I have designed a web page but till now I have a bad problem that I can't find the answer. The HTML markup is like the one below:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="strip">
            <div class="menu-item-holder">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    item1
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    |
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    item2
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    |
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    item3
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    |
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    item4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="body">
            
            <div class="context">
                
                <div class="header">
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="sticky-menu">
                
                    <div class="menu-item-holder">
                        
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            item1
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            |
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            item2
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            |
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            item3
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            |
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-item">
                            item4
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="upper-divs">
                    
                    <div class="up-left-div">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="up-right-div">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="left-block">
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="middle-block">
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="post">
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="right-block">
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer">
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>

And the style is like this:

    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    .body{
        width:1000px;
        height:100%;
        min-height:1600px;
        background:#cccccc;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:right !important;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding-top:40px;
    }
    
    .strip{
        width:100%;
        min-height:50px;
        background:#212121;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:center !important;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
    }
    
    .menu-item-holder{
        margin:0 auto !important;
        text-align:center;
        padding:11px;
    }
    
    .menu-item{
        display:inline;
        direction:rtl;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .context{
        background:#a0a0a0;
        width:86%;
        height:100%;
        min-height:1350px;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:right !important;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    .footer{
        width:99.8%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:#212121;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:right !important;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    .header{
        width:99.8%;
        min-height:350px;
        background:#ec2327;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:right !important;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
    .sticky-menu{
        width:99.8%;
        min-height:50px;
        background:#212121;
        direction:rtl !important;
        text-align:right !important;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:11px;
    }
    
    .upper-divs{
        margin-top:5px;
        width:99.8%;
        min-height:206px;
    }
    
    .up-left-div{
        width:49%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:white;
        float:left;
    }
    
    .up-right-div{
        width:49%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:white;
        float:right;
    }
    
    .left-block{
        width:18%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:white;
        float:left;
    }
    
    .middle-block{
        width:61.8%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:black;
        float:left;
        margin-left:1%;
        margin-right:1%;
    }
    
    .right-block{
        width:18%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:white;
        float:left;
    }
    
    .post{
        width:98%;
        min-height:200px;
        background:red;
        float:left;
        margin:5px;;
    }
```

And now the result is this:

[result](http://cclever.ir/peyman/)

I want to know, why the height of div of `body` class and the `div` of `context` class doesn't match to its children, why they are overflowing? But the `div` of `class` `middle-block` has the height of its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a little change- `overflow: auto;`

```
.context{
    background:#a0a0a0;
    width:86%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:1350px;
    direction:rtl !important;
    text-align:right !important;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was excelent ... i mean it needed least change to my code every thing was fixed !!! thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make parent: display:inline block; and children: display:inline; If you want parents to stretch to longest child, then you can try display table and display table cell too.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden to .context. That does the job more times than height:100%.
The same applies to .body as well.